# How to Disable Single Product Page in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am building an e-commerce site with **Woocommerce 3.6.4 + Wordpress 5.2.2**.

I tried to **disable the single product page of WooCommerce** so that people can shop directly from my shop page.

Tried:

**1. Add the code below to my child theme's functions.php file, didn't work.**

```
remove_action( ‘woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item’,‘woocommerce_template_loop_product_link_open’, 10 );
remove_action( ‘woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item’,‘woocommerce_template_loop_product_link_close’, 5 );
```

**2. Add the same code to my WooCommerce `content-product.php file`. Didn't work.**

3.`/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/templates/content-product.php`

Make these code as comments:

```
        do_action( ‘woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item’);
        do_action( ‘woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item’);
```

Become like this:

```
       //do_action( ‘woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item’);
       //do_action( ‘woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item’);
```

**It removed the link to the shopping page, but didn't remove the single product page.**

Any advice or help, please?

As a person who knows nothing about coding, this is literally driving me crazy!!!

**Can anyone help me, please? Any suggestion would be great!!**

Below is the **wp_content/themes/my_theme/woocommerce/content-product.php**:

```
    `<?php
/**
 * The template for displaying product content within loops
 *
 * This template can be overridden by copying it to yourtheme/woocommerce/content-product.php.
 *
 * HOWEVER, on occasion WooCommerce will need to update template files and you
 * (the theme developer) will need to copy the new files to your theme to
 * maintain compatibility. We try to do this as little as possible, but it does
 * happen. When this occurs the version of the template file will be bumped and
 * the readme will list any important changes.
 *
 * @see     https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/
 * @author  WooThemes
 * @package WooCommerce/Templates
 * @version 3.6.0
 */
defined( 'ABSPATH' ) || exit;
`

    <li  <?php wc_product_class( '', $product ); ?> data-product-id="<?php the_ID(); ?>">
    <?php
    /**
     * Hook: woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item.
     *
     * @hooked woocommerce_template_loop_product_link_open - 10
     */
    do_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item' );?>

    <?php if ('yes' != $themify->hide_product_image) : ?>
        <?php

        /**
         * Hook: woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title.
         *
         * @hooked woocommerce_show_product_loop_sale_flash - 10
         * @hooked woocommerce_template_loop_product_thumbnail - 10
         */
        do_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title' );

        ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <div class="product-content">
        <div class="product-content-inner-wrapper">
            <div class="product-content-inner">
                <?php
                /**
                 * Hook: woocommerce_shop_loop_item_title.
                 *
                 * @hooked woocommerce_template_loop_product_title - 10
                 */
                do_action( 'woocommerce_shop_loop_item_title' );


                /**
                 * Hook: woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item.
                 *
                 * @hooked woocommerce_template_loop_product_link_close - 5
                 * @hooked woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart - 10
                 */
                do_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item' );

                ?>
                <div class="product-share-wrap">
                    <?php Themify_Wishlist::button() ?>
                    <?php if (themify_hide_quick_look()): ?>
                        <a onclick="return false;" data-image="<?php echo wc_placeholder_img_src() ?>" class="quick-look themify-lightbox" href="<?php echo add_query_arg(array('post_in_lightbox' => '1'), get_permalink()) ?>"><span class="tooltip"><?php _e('Quick Look', 'themify'); ?></span></a>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                    <?php if (themify_hide_social_share()): ?>
                        <?php get_template_part('includes/social-share', 'product'); ?>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /.summary -->
</li>
```

Comment: why not redirect users from single product page to shop page if visited... that way user won't be able to access single page anyway...

Answer (score 1):

In your themes functions.php add the code,

```
// remove single product page link
remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item','woocommerce_template_loop_product_link_open', 10 );
remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item','woocommerce_template_loop_product_link_close', 5 );

// hide single product page completely
add_filter( 'woocommerce_register_post_type_product','hide_product_page',12,1);
function hide_product_page($args){
  $args["publicly_queryable"]=false;
  $args["public"]=false;
  return $args;
}
```

solution was partly based on @Vitaly Gritsienko 's answer